# storing indeterminate checkbox state

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, wiki

I've got some js to toggle my check boxes between checked indeterminate and unchecked. when the check box is checked it stores in my database as 1 when it is unchecked stores as 0 however i cannot figure out how to store a value when the checkbox is on indeterminate state it just sets it to 0. I've tried an onclick function I've tried getElementById I've tried setAttribute however nothing seems to work. The column does not have a default value in my db any help would be greatly appreciated !

PHP

```
 $schDone =isset($_POST['schDone']);
```

JS

```
  <script>
$("#some-checkbox").prop("indeterminate", true); // prop is jQuery 1.6+
var $check = $("input[type=checkbox]"), el;
$check
.data('checked',0)
.click(function(e) {

    el = $(this);

    switch(el.data('checked')) {

        // unchecked, going checked
        case 0:
            el.data('checked',1);
            el.prop('checked',true);
        document.getElementById("schDone").value = "1";

            break;


        // going indeterminate
        case 1:
            el.data('checked',2);
            el.prop('indeterminate',true);
            el.prop('checked',false);            
            document.getElementById("schDone").value = "3";

            break;

        // indeterminate going unchecked
        default:  
            el.data('checked',0);
            el.prop('indeterminate',false);
            el.prop('checked',false);
           document.getElementById("schDone").value = "0";
    }

});
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<td width="100px"bgcolor="#A7D0FE"><strong>Sch Done</strong></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id="schDone" name='schDone' <?php if($row['schDone']==1){echo 'checked="checked"';}  ?> value="1"></td>
```

Comment: Maybe this is just a typo here in SO, but you never properly close that checkbox-tag. You're JS is also trying to fetch the checkbox with `getElementById()` while the checkbox doesn't have an ID.

Comment: "*The indeterminate state is visual only. The checkbox is still either checked or unchecked as a state.*" - In other words, you will have to handle passing a secondary state using ajax so that PHP actually knows what it is you are wanting to save. As going by the value of a POST will not do it (unless you store the secondary state in a hidden input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for all the help i just had to make a hidden field and assign it depending on the state of my checkbox and then store that into my database. Didnt have to use filter or anything special and added a bit of code to display checkbox in correct state when coming out of the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery .filter function

Your Checkbox should have class like this

```
<td><input type='checkbox' name='schDone' <?php if($row['schDone']==1){echo 'checked="checked"';}  ?> value="1" class='schDone'></td>
```

Then your jquery code can be like this.

```
$('.schDone').filter(':checked', function() { // do whatever you want here });
```

Preferably, you can add a hidden field for setting the value if checked

i.e

```
<input type='hidden' class='is-checked' name='is-checked' value=''>
```

Then you can say

```
$('.schDone').filter(':checked', function() { 
  $('.is-checked').val(1); 
})
```